# upload file ok only if everything true or one file is wrong, if one of them empty this is wrong using codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am new in codeigniter 4 and I have two input files, they can be null in database, with my controller if they are true and select image, my code is fine, if one of them not image, my code is fine, but if one of them is empty my code is wrong, both verification was checked, for example if profile be selected image and TestImage not selected, result say test and die. please help! thank you.

in my view:

```
<section class="col-12 col-lg-4">
  <label for="ProfileUrl">Profile Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="ProfileUrl" id="ProfileUrl" placeholder="choose your image"
      class="form-control bg-input border-boot rounded-5"/>
         <?php if ($validation->getError('ProfileUrl')): ?>
            <div class='alert alert-danger mt-2'>
                <?= $error = $validation->getError('ProfileUrl'); ?>
            </div>
         <?php endif; ?>
</section>
<section class="col-12 col-lg-4">
  <label for="TestImage">test Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="TestImage" id="TestImage" placeholder="choose your image"
    class="form-control bg-input border-boot rounded-5"/>
</section>
```

my controller:

```
if ($ImageFile_2 = $this->request->getFile('ProfileUrl')):
            $validated_2 = $this->validate([
                'file' => [
                    'uploaded[ProfileUrl]',
                    'mime_in[ProfileUrl,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png]',
                    'max_size[ProfileUrl,4096]',
                ]
            ]);
            if ($validated_2) {
                if ($ImageFile_2->isValid() && !$ImageFile_2->hasMoved()) {
                    $newName = $ImageFile_2->getRandomName();
                    $ImageFile_2->move(WRITEPATH . 'uploads', $newName);
                    $UploadPath = '' . WRITEPATH . 'uploads\\' . $newName;
                    $data_register['profile_img_url'] = $UploadPath;
                }
            } else {
                echo 'profile';
                die();
            }
        endif;
        if (($ImageFile_1 = $this->request->getFile('TestImage'))):
            $validated_1 = $this->validate([
                'file' => [
                    'uploaded[TestImage]',
                    'mime_in[TestImage,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png]',
                    'max_size[TestImage,4096]',
                ]
            ]);
            if ($validated_1) {
                if ($ImageFile_1->isValid() && !$ImageFile_1->hasMoved()) {
                    $newName = $ImageFile_1->getRandomName();
                    $ImageFile_1->move(WRITEPATH . 'uploads', $newName);
                    $UploadPath = '' . WRITEPATH . 'uploads\\' . $newName;
                    $data_register['test_img'] = $UploadPath;
                }
            } else {
                echo 'test';
                die();
            }
        endif;
```

thanks

Comment: edit: wait... I now see the "if".. is there a reason for mixing this two notations? -There is an standalone "endif;" for which there is no "if", eg. code snippet is incomplete.- Furthermore, "code is wrong" isn't very helpful.. what's your definition of "wrong" or "right"?

Comment: thank you, IF first file select and second was empty, first & second function work, I want if file select in each of them they work @LarsStegelitz

Comment: Remove "die()" ... you know what this is doing, do you?

Comment: yes I know, I add "die()" for test, also I removed it before I ask question and same problem; :) @LarsStegelitz

Comment: Do you maybe mean the missing validation-failed message for the TestImage? The one without the appropriate HTML block?

Comment: no I not want error message, the TestImage input not necessary for client. I want if this id empty, information just recorded in database. if two input select file, form work. and if one file select not image file, error works fine. I want if one of them not select any file, form works. @LarsStegelitz

Comment: `I want if this id empty, information just recorded in database.` which information? if id is null, there is no information (except null of course). I suppose, when no file is select, the `getFile()` will be null/false, which will skip the whol block. Since there is no else-branch for the case that `getFile` return null, you'd have to write one...

Comment: oh I'm sorry "this id empty" I mean "this is empty", yes you're right about id, and exactly the point when no file selected it must skip whole block and the problem is, not skip happen when no file selected.@LarsStegelitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with this,

```
$ImageFile_1 = $this->request->getFile('ProfileUrl');

            if ($ImageFile_1 && $ImageFile_1->getSize()>1)
```

if I check each file size more than 1 byte.